# How to change `view options` in download/browse window dialog?

Tags: finder

I know how to change `view options` in Finder. But I failed to figure out how to change `view options` in download/browse window dialog. Many apps will allow you to browse files/folders with a popup window dialog (I think it's a part of finder), for instance, there will be a popup window for you to choose where to download a file in `chrome` app. I tried the shortcut `Command + j`, it doesn't do anything. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I would like to change some default settings such as disabling preview etc...

**Edited:** Since people don't quite understand what I mean by `download/browse` window in the comments, please check the following screenshot for an example:

[image]

You can see that the `show icon preview` is enabled by default in the popup window. I failed to turn it off since I can not launch `command + j` view options window in this dialog. Btw, in case if you doubt, I have turned off (disabled) `show icon preview` option in all folders and set it off as defaults. There is no preview at all if I open any folders in `Finder`.

Comment: What is a ‘download/browse window’? In which app or apps does this window appear?

Comment: Please consider [editing]() your question and clarify what is it that you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to change the icon view mode or change other setting?

Comment: @IconDaemon
@NimeshNeema
I think I have clarified what `download/browse` window dialog is in my original post. I even provided an example such as the popup window to choose where to download a file in `chrome` app. Whatever, I will provide a screenshot of chrome after posting this comment. Cheers.